# Xfce screen goes black after some time

Tags: xfce, screensaver

My Xfce goes black after some time when I'm not using computer. I already checked from setting/screensaver that mode is set to be disable screen saver, but the screen still goes black. How can I make sure that I can watch World Cup matches without screen going to black? Do I need some script that presses for example shift button every couple of minutes?

Comment: Can you add an image of your lightlocker settings?

Comment: I haven't a homepage to put that image but Blanc screen after = 10 minutes, Switch off display after ... 15 minutes, Enable light locked ON, Automatically lock the session Never, Lock on suspend Off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Blank screen after, and Switch off display after are both disabled, and screen saver is Off.  See image below.

[image]